# Saving and deleting data from firestore async

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

I am able to display data stored in firestore, but now i want to add/delete products.

My **ViewModel**

```
private val repository = FirebaseRepository()
private var _products = MutableLiveData<List<Product>>()
val products: LiveData<List<Product>> get() = _products

init {
    viewModelScope.launch{
        val id = repository.getCurrentUserId()
        val user = repository.getUserData(id)
        try {
            repository.getList(user!!.groupId.toString())
                .collect { items ->
                    _products.value = items
                }
        } catch (e: Throwable){
            /* TODO */
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to rewrite my *addProduct* function, to add product to group that user belongs to. So again i need to get user data,  which is suspend function and need to be called from coroutine scope.

That's my function without coroutines in repository

```
 fun addProduct(groupId: String, product: Product){
    db.collection("group")
        .document(groupId)
        .collection("Objects")
        .add(product)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.d("REPO_DEBUG", "Added")
        }
        .addOnFailureListener{
            Log.d("REPO_DEBUG", it.message.toString())
        }
}
```

And in view model class

```
  fun addProduct(product: Product){

    repository.addProduct("xGRWy21hwQ7yuBGIJtnA", product)
}
```

How can I transform it to work async? Should I mark all firestore operation functions as suspend and use scopes or is it not necessary?

*adding and updating is done via dialog fragments, delating via swipa (I already have it implemented but as I said it works without coroutines)

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think you might be interested in reading this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8).

Comment: Idk why my question was marked as duplicate. I just want to know how correctly use it  and there are not many articles about firestore with coroutines. @Alex so should I add suspend modifier to all query functions in repo, and then in view model do the same and create scope insinde each function?

Comment: That's not only about adding the `suspend` keyword. However, the duplicate answer will solve your problem.